# add row to access table and set user details

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, rows

I am working on an automated registration page for my site and have come up against a brick wall (as I'm quite new to vb.net and databases).  I needs to add a new row and fill in the users details they have entered to the registration page.  The code I have is as follows. I have tried several things but nothing has worked, so the below code is just what I have to open the connection and set details. Any help would be really wonderful.  Thank you.

```
Dim oPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/app_data/IOFR.mdb")

Dim oReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Nothing
Dim oConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing

Dim oName As String = txtName.Text
Dim oUserName as String = ""
Dim oPassword as String = ""
Dim oActiveAcc As String = ""
Dim ologged As String = ""
Dim oOrg As String = ""
Dim oTel as String = ""
Dim oEmail as String = ""
Dim oTown as String = ""
Dim oRegStart as String = ""
Dim oSubscribedUser As String = ""


oConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxxxxx", oPath))
oConnection.Open()

Dim ipAddress As String = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

Dim oCommandSession As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Users SET [Name] = @oName", oConnection)
oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oName", oName))
oCommandSession.ExecuteNonQuery()

If Not oConnection Is Nothing Then
If oConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
    oConnection.Close()
End If
End If
```

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you are not using the `pmUserid` parameter in your query - you have written `oUserid` (without `@`) there. Do you actually have to include the `@` in the `new OleDbParameter` constructor - I am not sure?  Anyhow, it is hard to help you without any additional information. What results and/or errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks CompuChip, you are right, the pmUserid above is not used in the above, should have Dim oUserId as integer = 0.  The above code works in that it updates the cells with the regiter's name but i need to new code that would fit with the above to insert a new row to the database table then I can use the above to input the register's details. :)  sorry if my language is not great as im not a pro sadley.

Comment: OK so I amended my above post to show the exact code that i'm using.  It does take the users name but updates the "Name" column for each row.  The goal i am trying to achieve is to add a new row then add the user name ie, to update the database with a new user.  But i'm not sure who to do this. :(

Comment: Your update doesn't have a where-clause hence it will update all rows on the table. Also I don't think you need update here, you need an insert (insert into users Values (@Name, @UserName...). Familiarize yourself to sql and generate appropriate insert-clause with ALL the needed parameters.

Comment: Thanks Esa. Great comment. I knew I should have the where Clause but I didn't know what condition to put after. Insert makes perfect sense. I will give it a try and post back here. Going forward I will be sure to study sql in much more deapth. Thanks aj